# Showing plagiarism results

Tags: java, preprocessor, highlighting, plagiarism-detection

I am in a process of developing a plagiarism detection framework. There we first preprocess the documents in the means of stemming, synonym replacement and stop word removal. So the preprocessed document is somewhat different from the original document.

After we enter the preprocessed document to our plagiarism function it returns the similar sentences.

Then in our  GUI we have to display the two documents and the similar sentences by highlighting.

To highlight in java we have to get the index of the words and highlight.

The problem is that the preprocessed text is different from the original document so it is difficult to index the similar sentences in the original document.

Can anyone help me with this problem ??

Comment: Is this a homework assignment from someone with a sense of irony?

Comment: already been done : Simian - Similarity Analyser: http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: second part of the assignment is to run on its own code!!  (Covers recursion nicely too!)

Comment: why dont you use gvimdiff? There might be an option to align the files given that there is an offset between the two.

Comment: @Andrew: In the best tradition of digging your own grave...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to store some sort of metadata with the preprocessed document that allows to map the content of it to the original document. Like keeping a list of all gaps that result from stop word removal or storing information on where you replaced words with synonyms.

If you record every change that has been made during preprocessing (location/replaced text) then you should be able to find the original phrase in the original document.

Comment: Agreed: the core of a solution is to keep track of how the original document was transformed. That could be stop word / whitespace / punctuation removal, in which case the transformation is still linear (and diff could be used as the core technology), but perhaps sentences can be reordered? In that case, you'll need to have a map of what fragments moved to where.